# How can a threading function call another function for getting its value?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, operating-system, gil

There is a threading function that requires to call another function for carrying out it's operation.
For example,

```py
import requests
from threading import Thread
threads = []
urls = { 
    'google.com' : (1, 20),
    'facebook.com' : (3, 7),
    'example.com' : (4, 10),
    ...  # The urls dictionary is quite big
}
details_dict = dict()

def get_details_from_url(url, page_no):
    response = requests.get(url+str('?page=')+page_no)
    return response.json()

def get_details_of_many_pages(url, starting_page, ending_page):
    results = []
    for page in range(starting_page, ending_page):
        json_resp = get_details_from_url(url, page)
        results.append(json_resp)
    print(f"Got results from {url} for pages {starting_page}-{ending_page}")
    details_dict[url] = results.copy()

for url, start, end in urls.items():
    thread = Thread(target= get_details_of_many_pages, args= (url, start, end))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print("All details have been recorded")
```

Suppose both the 'get_details_from_url' function is called from the 'get_details_of_many_pages' function and each iteration takes more than 2 seconds time in between their respective operations. My question is, will one thread's operation affect the other thread with respect to the data transfer between two functions and the data getting appended in a local list?, as they both will be calling the 'get_details_from_url' function and that function will be returning a value, which is being stored inside a list.

My belief is that the data of each thread could get corrupted because of the values clashing each other and also the local variables could also get corrupted. Is that so? Or will this work just fine?

Comment: Are you asking whether the `print` function is thread safe? If not, then what? Apart from the `print` call, the threads don't share any variables.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The add() which I am calling takes more than 2 seconds, will it effect other threads of add_fast() from using the add() function?

Comment: If not for your "takes more than 2 seconds" comment, I'd have said that `add(a,b)` is completely trivial. It does not access any variables that could be shared between threads. But, I don't understand the "2 seconds" comment. Your example shows `add(a,b)` being called on small integer arguments. How can adding two small integers take more than two seconds?

Comment: I am sorry @SolomonSlow I used a very bad example for my question. I have now edited the question and I hope it should be clear what the program will be doing. If not, please ping again.

Comment: OK, so the answer depends on whether `requests.get(url)` is thread safe. I don't know the answer to that one. Also, I'm not so sure about `results.append(...)`. In any _other_ language, you would need to lock a mutex in order to add something to any kind of collection. But, Python has the GIL. I don't know whether the GIL makes `append` an atomic operation or not.